# Change of variables in Heat Equation (and Fourier Series)

Tags: fourier-series, change-of-variable

Q: Suppose $u(x,t)$ satisfies the heat equation for $0<x<a$ with the usual initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$, and the temperature given to be a non-zero constant C on the surfaces $x=0$ and $x=a$.

We have BCs $u(0,t) = u(a,t) = C.$ Our standard method for finding u doesn't work here, since $e^{-k(\frac{n\pi}a)^2t}sin(\frac{n\pi}a)$ does not satisfy these BCs.

Make a change of variable from $u$ to $v=u-C.$ Show that $v$ satisfies the heat equation with BCs $v=0$ at $x=0$ and $x=a.$

Write down the solution for $v(x,t).$Deduce an expression for $u(x,t)$ in terms of constants $c_1,c_2,\ldots,$ and write down a formula for $c_n.$

[Harder] Now suppose the BCs are $u(0,t) = C$, $u(a,t)=D$ for constants $C,D.$ How could you solve the case?

My question: These are extensions to homework which I'd like try to attempt, but I don't know where to start with the change of variable

Comment: What if $f = 0$ ? Can you find a solution satisfying the boundary conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\partiald{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}}{t} =
> D\,\partiald[2]{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}}{x}\,,\quad
> D > 0\,,\ x \in \pars{0,a}\,;\qquad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{0,t} = \mrm{u}\pars{a,t} = C\,,\quad \forall\ t > 0}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,0} = \mrm{f}\pars{x}}
> \end{array}\right.}$

Write $\ds{\,\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} =
C + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{t}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}}$ such that $\ds{\braces{\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{t}}}$ satisfy
$$
\totald{a_{n}\pars{t}}{t} = -D\,\pars{n\pi \over a}^{2}\,\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{t}
$$.

---

The general solution is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} =
C + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}
\exp\pars{-D\,\bracks{n\pi \over a}^{2}t}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

$\ds{\braces{\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0}}}$ is determined by:
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & = \,\mrm{u}\pars{x,0} =
C + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}
\\[5mm] 
\int_{0}^{a}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}\,\dd x & = 
C\overbrace{\int_{0}^{a}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{{2a \over \pi}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{n\pi/2} \over n}}} +
\sum_{m =1}^{\infty}\mrm{a}_{m}\pars{0}
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{a}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}
\sin\pars{m\pi\,{x \over a}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{{1 \over 2}\,a\,\delta_{mn}}}
\end{align}

---

$$\bbx{\ds{%
\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0} =
{2 \over a}\int_{0}^{a}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\sin\pars{n\pi\,{x \over a}}\,\dd x -
{4 \over \pi}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{n\pi/2} \over n}\,C}}\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \eqref{1}~}
$$

> In your '$\bracks{Harder}$' case we add $\ds{C + \pars{D - C}\,{x \over a}}$  to the series instead of $\ds{C}$. Hereafter, the derivation is quite similar to the above one.

Comment: Could you explain where the ${\ds{{1 \over 2}\,a\,\delta_{mn}}}$ comes from and what it means?

Comment: @user3613025 When $m \not= n$ the integral vanishes out. Otherwise,
$$
\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{2}\left({n\pi \over a}\,x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{0}^{a}{1 - \cos\left(2n\pi x/a\right) \over 2}\,\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{0}^{a}{1 \over 2}\,\mathrm{d}x = {1 \over 2}\,a
$$
The '$\cos$-integration' vanishes out.